# Using TouchableOpacity with primary transparent gives typescript error

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

Below is the Code what i am trying to execute using typescript and react-native and it gives me typescript error in VSCODE IDE

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

<TouchableOpacity
    primary
    transparent
    onPress={this.send}
>
    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Send</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

> gives following typescript error in VSCode:

```
(alias) class TouchableOpacity
import TouchableOpacity
No overload matches this call.

Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps>): TouchableOpacity', gave the following error.

Type '{ children: Element; primary: true; transparent: true; onPress: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Property 'primary' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TouchableOpacityProps, context?: any): TouchableOpacity', gave the following error.

Type '{ children: Element; primary: true; transparent: true; onPress: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Property 'primary' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2769)
```

Comment: `Property 'primary' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.` It says, it cannot find a prop named PRIMARY inside the typing of TouchableOpacity. Try to remove it, please see: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity#props for a list of valid props.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use props that are not available in `TouchableOffacity`.

```js
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
    onPress={this.send}
>
```